# Make Forecolor Button in TinyMCE behave differently

Tags: tinymce

I want to make forecolor in tinymce behave differently. Where can I change that in code?

I want forecolor not to work for elements with certain class.

For example, I have `<span class="test">Here is span</span>`.

When I select text and click change color, by default TINYMCE will generate something like `<span class="test"><span style="color:rgb(234,51,24)">Here is span</span></span>`.

I want it differently, I want to write it as `<span class="test">color(234,51,24)Here is span</span>`.
Such modification should be only for elements with class "test".

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you will have to develop an own plugin or modify the behaviour that is present for now. There is now way to configure this, beacuse what you want is somehwat special.